# parse time string type back to time type error

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    source := "2014-04-22 23:41:12.518845115 +0800 CST"
    Form := "2014-04-22 23:41:12.518845115 +0800 CST"
    t, err := time.Parse(Form, source)

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(t.String())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Error :`parsing time "2014-04-22 23:41:12 +0800 CST": month out of range`

I get `source` by `time.Now().String()`, but I could not convert it back. What's wrong with this piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it
>   represents. **The layout defines the format by showing how the reference
>   time,**
>
> **Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006 would be interpreted if it were the**
>
> **value**; it serves as an example of the input format. The same
>   interpretation will then be made to the input string. Predefined
>   layouts ANSIC, UnixDate, RFC3339 and others describe standard and
>   convenient representations of the reference time. For more information
>   about the formats and the definition of the reference time, see the
>   documentation for ANSIC and the other constants defined by this
>   package.

(Bolding mine).

So what you want is

```
Form := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000 -0700 MST"
```

Which is the date listed in that quote in the format of your input string. One thing to note while I was writing this on the playground to confirm is that it looks like on the part `05.000000000` (the seconds and fractions of seconds) you need the format string to contain *exactly* as many decimal points as the string you want to parse.

Here's a playground version showing it works: http://play.golang.org/p/dRniJbqgl7

Comment: Thanks. The decimal point of `source` and `form` is the same. I think the `-0700 MST` part is the reason.